# How to bend object with shaders in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, vertex-shader

I have a shader script with which I bend the world. But the problem is that this script only bends up and down. How to add so that you can both left and right?

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced '_Object2World' with 'unity_ObjectToWorld'
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced '_World2Object' with 'unity_WorldToObject'

Shader "Custom/Bendy Diffuse - Radial" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _ReflectionColor ("Reflection Tint Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert addshadow
        #pragma multi_compile __ HORIZON_WAVES 
        #pragma multi_compile __ BEND_ON

        // Global properties to be set by BendControllerRadial script
        uniform half3 _CurveOrigin;
        uniform fixed3 _ReferenceDirection;
        uniform half _Curvature;
        uniform fixed3 _Scale;
        uniform half _FlatMargin;
        uniform half _HorizonWaveFrequency;

        // Per material properties
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _ReflectionColor;

        struct Input 
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half4 Bend(half4 v)
        {
            half4 wpos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v);

            half2 xzDist = (wpos.xz - _CurveOrigin.xz) / _Scale.xz;

            half dist = length(xzDist);
            fixed waveMultiplier = 1;

            dist = max(0, dist - _FlatMargin);

            wpos.y -= dist * dist * _Curvature * waveMultiplier;

            wpos = mul (unity_WorldToObject, wpos);

            return wpos;
        }

        void vert (inout appdata_full v) 
        {
            #if defined(BEND_ON)
            v.vertex = Bend(v.vertex);  
            #endif
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;

            fixed4 detail = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            fixed4 refl = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);

            o.Albedo = detail.rgb * _Color.rgb;
            o.Alpha = 1;
            o.Emission = refl.rgb * _ReflectionColor.rgb;
        }
        ENDCG

    }

    Fallback "Mobile/Specular/Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: it's usually better to copy the code into the question instead of linking to a third party file hoster.

Comment: It looks like it should already be bending based on distance along x and z dimensions. Can you provide an image of what you already have, and also maybe a  mockup of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to create an illusion of curved Earth. You have xzDist, add this vector multiplied by unmodified Y. So basically if it's left from origin point, bend it left. Points that are hight will bend away from the center more, and the ones below the equator could bend to the center. Can't promise that this will look right though.